# How to query AWS DocumentDB (DocDB) to compare two fields using $where

Tags: mongodb, aws-documentdb

AWS's DocumentDB is not the same as Mongo -- specifically, you cannot use the `$where` operator in find queries.  Specifically, I wish to make a query that will show me all results where document fields `x` == `y`, e.g.:

```
> db.my_collection.find({$where:"this.x==this.y"}).pretty();
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "operationTime" : Timestamp(1623784861, 1),
    "code" : 303,
    "errmsg" : "Feature not supported: $where"
}
```

How is this done in DocDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a possible workaround to get the results close to what you expect in DocumentDB. It is similar to a SQL self-join without the `WHERE`.
You would need to extract the **joined** element if you want it exactly as it appears in MongoDB. Please note that the use of aggregate across large volumes may have performance implications when compared to `$where` operator. As always please do test before deploying to production.

Below are the steps used to test the query in DocumentDB

- Sample data

> ```
> db.tableA.insert( { "id":"123", "key1":"fjf", "key2":[{},{}] } )
>
> db.tableA.insert( { "id":"123", "key1":"xyz", "key2":[{"x": "1"},{"y": "1"}], "key3": "123" } )
>
> db.tableA.insert( { "id":"456", "key1":"abc", "key3": "456" } )
> ```

- Query

> ```
> db.tableA.aggregate([
> {
>     $lookup:
>         {
>           from: "tableA",
>           localField: "id",
>           foreignField: "key3",
>           as: "joined"
>         }
> },
> { $unwind :"$joined" },
> {  $redact: { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$key3", "$joined.key3" ] }, "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE" ] } }
> { $project: { joined: 1, _id: 0 } }
> ]).pretty()
> ```